# Pandas / How to convert scientific notation stored as strings into float?

Tags: python, pandas, casting, scientific-notation

I have a list with values stored as strings. Some of the values are stored with scientific notation and others are floats. I tried to cast them using .astype(float) but It didn't work. Any idea on how to deal with this?

My goal is to get the column as float.

```
df['Colum1] = ['5,4e-05','3,35e-05','0,0001125','0,0001335']
```

Comment: try replacing your commas `,` with periods `.` the pandas devs are from the US and that's how decimal notation works there

Answer (score 2):

First you have to replace the commas for dots, then you can just cas to `float`:

```
df.Colum1.str.replace(',', '.').astype(float)
```

Also to prevent from any errors, `pd.to_numeric` is probably the best option:

```
pd.to_numeric(df.Col1.str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')
```

---

Here's an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col1':['5,4e-05','3,35e-05','0,0001125','0,0001335']})

pd.to_numeric(df.Col1.str.replace(',', '.'), errors='coerce')

0    0.000054
1    0.000034
2    0.000112
3    0.000133
Name: Col1, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Thank you very much!